# From YUV to Y4M ffmpeg adapting

Tags: ffmpeg

I was used this command to convet some YUV videos in m4v, note that I was using a video in CIF format:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 -g 30 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

Now I downloaded a 720p movie and want to have the same paramethers

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i video.y4m -vcodec libx264 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

I erased "-s cif" because I read that the headers in y4m already have the resolution.
I'm getting the error "frame hate not found".

Comment: You should always include the complete ffmpeg console output when asking questions about ffmpeg cli (which are off-topic here: try [su] next time).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Whatś the difference between stackoverflow and su ? There the focus is more in ffmpeg ?

Comment: Why your question + answer of difference between ffmpeg and avconv or libav is here and not there ? :)

Answer (score -1):

I just put :

ffmpeg -i video.y4m -vcodec libx264 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v

And now it works.

Comment: Yes LordNeckbeard, you repeat it all the time and I think I recorded well :). But in this case I put to force the ffmpeg to keep the same quantization matriz of the original video. Thanks for clarify again.

Comment: Your usage of `-sameq` still does not made sense, and this option has been removed from ffmpeg anyway.

Comment: Yes it does. When I put -sameq I'm look to do not re-compact the original quantization matriz.